# Create JSON object out of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these values:

```
var firstHeader = $('#header0').text(); // 6KP
var secondHeader = $('#header1').text(); // 7KP
var thirdHeader = $('#header2').text(); // 8KP

var first = $('#input0').val(); // 77
var second = $('#input1').val(); //88
var third = $('#input2').val(); // 99
```

And I need to create a JSON object to have this:

```
{6KP:77, 7KP:88, 8KP:99}
```

I tried to do this but without success:

```
var data = { firstHeader: first, secondHeader: second, thirdHeader: third };

data = JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ');
```

And my response is this:

```
{firstHeader: 77, secondHeader:88, thirdHeader:99}
```

How can I put the values instead of these var names?

Comment: I know there are multiple dupes of this, btw, so searching first is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use array notation, e.g.,

```
var data = {}; 
data[firstHeader] = first;
```

If you're using ES6 you can use the shorthand:

```
var data = { 
  [firstHeader]: first, 
  // Etc.
};
```

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal It will if you're using ES6, e.g., transpiling or in an environment where it's supported. I made no mention of it working natively--I said "using ES6" on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use square brackets to evaluate the variable value as a key name:

```
var data = {};
data[firstHeader] = first;
data[secondHeader] = second;
data[thirdHeader] = third;
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```js
var firstHeader = '6KP';
var secondHeader = '7KP';
var thirdHeader = '8KP';

var first = '77';
var second = '88';
var third = '99';
var data = {};
data[firstHeader] = first;
data[secondHeader] = second;
data[thirdHeader] = third;
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace below line

```
var data = { firstHeader: first, secondHeader: second, thirdHeader: third };
```

with

```
var data ={};

data[firstHeader]= first;
data[secondHeader]= second;
data[thirdHeader]: third ;
```